# Regress each column in a data frame on a vector in R

Tags: r, statistics

I want to regress each column in a data set on a vector then return the column which has the highest R-squared value. e.g. I have a vector HAPPY <- (3,2,2,3,1,3,1,3) and I have a data set.

```
HEALTH  CONINC  MARITAL SATJOB1 MARITAL2                    HAPPY
3           441 5        1            2                        3
1          1764 5        1            2                        2
2          3087 5        1            2                        2
3          3087 5        1            2                        3
1          3969 2        1            5                        1
1          3969 5        1            2                        3
2          4852 5        1            2                        2
3          5734 3        1            3                        3
```

Regress "Happy" on each of the columns in the data set on the left, then return the column which has the highest R-squared. Example:  lm(Health ~ Happy) if Health had the highest R-squared value, then return Health.

I've tried apply, but can't seem to figure out how to return the regression with the highest R-squared. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what you want, assuming your data.frame is called 'd'

```
r2s <- apply(d, 2, function(x) summary(lm(x ~ HAPPY))$r.squared)
names(d)[which.max(r2s)]
```

You can find out how to extract components of the model, or in this case, a summary of the model, with the str() command.  It will give you a read out that helps you access the components of any complex object.

Answer (score 5):

I would break this up into two steps:

1) Determine R-squares for each model

2) Determine which is the highest value

```
mydf<-data.frame(aa=rpois(8,4),bb=rpois(8,2),cc=rbinom(8,1,.5),
  happy=c(3,2,2,3,1,3,1,3))

myRes<-sapply(mydf[-ncol(mydf)],function(x){
  mylm<-lm(x~mydf$happy)
  theR2<-summary(mylm)$r.squared
  return(theR2)
})

names(myRes[which(myRes==max(myRes))])
```

This was assuming that `happy` is in your data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the `colwise()` function from the plyr package.

```
library(plyr)
df = data.frame(a = runif(10), b=runif(10), c=runif(10), d = runif(10))

Rsq = function(x) summary(lm(df$a ~ x))$r.squared

Rsqall = colwise(Rsq)(df[, 2:4])
Rsqall

names(Rsqall)[which.max(Rsqall)]
```

Comment: I used this solution the other day with RCDK.  I was searching for the highest r.squared value across all of the molecular descriptors in the chemical development kit library against the assay results from my molecules.  Thanks.